# Versioning infrastructure resources in Azure - ARM templates

Tags: azure, versioning, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

What is the best practice to version infrastructure in Azure?

I thought that I could use **contentVersion** element in the ARM templates and append the build number to  in Azure DevOps pipelines when deploying the ARM templates, so that I can see a version "1.0.5.20210322.2" in Azure Portal.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.5",
  "parameters": {  },
   ...
}
```

But in Azure when you on a resource choose "Export Template", you *always* get the same value for `contentVersion: "1.0.0.0"` no matter what you set it too when you deployed it. So this makes it rather useless.

The other approach I can think of is to use resourceTags:

[image]

But then tags can be removed by anyone with access to the subscription.

So not sure what the best practice is for versioning infrastructure in Azure. Recommendations are more than welcome as this if for a GxP project.

Comment: You can take look at Azure Blueprints it provides versioning capability https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/governance/blueprints/concepts/lifecycle

Comment: Know a bit about Blueprints but don't know if I can use this in connection with build and deployment in Azure DevOps. I need to stamp a version at the deployment time to an infrastructure resource.